# jQuery .change with .each inside not firing properly

Tags: jquery, each

I have a simple .change function that goes to the database and gets some values sets some values, ect.

```
$('.linequantity').change(function() {
    ...
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $('#TT-' + lineItem).text(parseFloat(data['price']) * quantity);
    });
});
```

What I want to then, is on any of the linequantites changing, I want to update the subtotal.  (Yes it's a catalog type/shopping cart style app).  My thought was, lets use a .each

```
$('.linequantity').each(function(){
     ...
   var url = "jQueryFunctions.php?action=getPrice&quantity=" + quantity + "&customer=" + customerID + "&item=" + lineItem;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       subtotal = subtotal + (parseFloat(data['price']) * quantity);
     });
   });

   $('#subtotal').text(subtotal);
```

when I do this though, I get 0 for the subtotal, if the each even fires at all.

I have tired putting the .each in a function. When I moved the .each into it's own function it fired more consistently, but the getJSON, which in the .change works just fine gets skipped.

Am I running into a conflict of the first json request isn't quite complete before I ask for another one?

I am open to a change in methodology, but thing the above has the right idea/start to it.

Any ideas?

**EDITS**
quantity field

```
<input type="text" class="linequantity" id="SQ-<?php echo $value['itemNumber']; ?>" name="Quantity" placeholder="#"/>
```

total span

```
<span id="subtotal" class="currencyField">$0.00</span>
```

11:44 EDIT:
I think the .each is hitting before the getJson completes.  How can I make sure the json request completed before I do not jQuery

Comment: What HTML elements have the class `linequantity` ? can you include your HTML ?

Comment: You could create an `action` for `getSubtotal` so you don't have to do this in a loop.

Comment: @ExplosionPills perhaps I am jQuery brainwashed, but what do you mean by action?

Comment: @ManseUK - updated with some html to support

Comment: Your own terminology (`jQueryFunctions.php?*action*=getSubtotal...`)

Comment: @ExplosionPills  I thought about doing that, having a running total in a db somewhere, but until they go and actually place the order I didn't want to have any rows in a table sitting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have a race condition whereby the ajax requests are completing too late.  The only way to get around this is to have methods that depend on the requests run after they complete.  There are a lot of ways to do this such as using `Deferred`  and `$.when`.  The simple way would be nice:

```
$.getJSON(...)
   .done(function () {
      // Stuff that depends on JSON goes here
   });
```

In the `.each` you are depending on multiple requests -- possibly a lot at a time.  I would try to do this in one request (e.g. update your server code to accept a list of items and compute the subtotal instead of just having them one at a time).  Otherwise, you have to update the subtotal continuously, which may cause it to flicker visually.  It's also inefficient for the server.  You may be able to do something like:

```
var jqXHRs = []
$.each(...
   jqXHRs.append($.getJSON(...));
);
$.when(jqXHRs).done(...);
```

...but I'm not sure whether `$.when` will work with an array like that, or if there is any way to expand the argument list to it.

Comment: I ended up going a completely different route with this issue, but read a lot about the jQuery events.  .done is the key to making sure that the event is complete before moving on to the next.  I accepted because you started me down road.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) should be used on  elements,  boxes and  elements only.

With that in mind, you probably need to make a call to $().val(); to get the active user selections / input data.

something like this might do it:

```
$('.linequantity').change(function() {
    var inputData = $(this).val();
    // other stuff!
});
```

Comment: the .change is over input fields. the ...'s above the getJSON are .val calls to get different things around the html page.